# How do I send an email through a Contact Form using Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, dart-pub

So I want users to be able to fill the form and send an email like the typical website Contact forms we have.

I have tried several libraries on pub dev, but non seems to do the job right, most only focus on IOS and Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

#### pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  url_launcher: ^5.7.1
```

#### import

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
```

#### to launch

```
_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://flutter.dev';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

#### URL schemes

[image]

Comment: Does flutter_email_sender support Web?

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out

Comment: I finally used the mailer plugin in flutter's pub library, pretty easy and straight to the point.
They basically both work the same way though.
Thanks so much for your input.